# get cssselector of svg tag in selenium...how to i get one paricular element in svg tag

Tags: java, selenium

I get total 22 list by using this css selector `#rph3 > svg > a > text>tspan....` I want a particular element.. how to find

```
Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fr search']")).sendKeys("mahindra and mahindra financial services");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fr search']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='acc3']//span[@class='rht fr'][contains(text(),'View All')]")).click();
        WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#rph3 > svg > a > text>tspan"));
```

Comment: How people will know, how the SVG element looks like, please add html structure of svg element  and read [MCVE]

Comment: String data = "//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='rect' and @height='40']";
  WebElement svgObject= driver.findElement(By.xpath(data));
     System.out.println(svgObject);
 why it didnot print my eement on my consol